# How to set the size of a span inside a span equal to the size of its parent?

Tags: html, css

[image]

[image]

How to set the size of a span inside a span equal to the size of its parent?

```
<span data-dvc-cd="R03" data-item-code="sCO" data-item-start="" data-item-end="" data-item-unit="" data-item-level1= "" data-item-level2="" data-item-level3="" class="on">
<span class="txt" style="width: 60px;">Carbon monoxide</span> </span>
```

That picture represents the code above.

If I click the location corresponding to .txt, it works normally, but if I click the location of the parent outside the txt, it works abnormally.

To solve this problem, I want to match the size of the inner span to the size of the parent.

If you increase the size of the child, the size of the parent also increases, changing the shape of the chart. I want to increase only the area of the child tag without changing the appearance of the chart, but I don't know how.

It is possible to have one span, but there is a restriction that txt should be placed in a span inside a span due to collaboration.

Best Regards!

Answer (score 0):

```
<span style="width: 60px;" data-dvc-cd="R03" data-item-code="sCO" data-item-start="" data-item-end="" data-item-unit="" data-item-level1= "" data-item-level2="" data-item-level3="" class="on">
<span class="txt" style="width: 100%;">Carbon monoxide</span> </span>
```